# Jinja "==" (compare condition) doesn't work?

Tags: html, django, templates, jinja2

while writing an application in django, I've encountered a problem. I want to make page-number links, with current page not being a link. So in template I do this:

```
{% for i in pages %} 
{% if i == curr_page %} {{ i }}
{% else %} <a href="...">{{ i }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Only problem? Jinja doesn't seem to notice two numbers being equal. I've changed the 2nd line to `{% if i != curr_page %} {{i}}!={{curr_page}}` and got "... 5!=6  6!=6  7!=6 ...".

What should I do?

Comment: are sure they are of same data type ? that means both are interger ? `pages` should be a list of integer and `curr_page` should be an integer too.

Comment: I have no idea, python is not particularly open about what's what type. I just send those variables in a dictionary, I assumed they are all strings. 


EDIT: Buy you're right, casting curr_page to int fixed the problem. Thanks:)

Comment: Before passing them to context dict convert them to `int`. `pages = list(map(int, pages))` and `curr_page = int(curr_page)`.

Comment: Ok. I posted this as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they are not of same data type. In your view, cast them to `int` before passing to context `dict`.

```
pages = list(map(int, pages))
curr_page = int(curr_page)
```